# How to write custom event loop policy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm researching the asyncio library and I cannot understand completely the reason behind event loop policies.

So far it's clear that this interface is a factory that returns event loop for current *context*. The definition of the context is not clear though. Apparently, the interface of [asyncio.AbstractEventLoopPolicy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoopPolicy) assumes that concrete implementation will be able to extract context on its own because neither method accepts arguments. This model works well for the event-loop-per-thread default policy, but usage under more sophisticated circumstances are under the question.

Looks like *context* isn't an arbitrary entity, but should follow certain rules (e.g. being visible globally). I wonder if such rules are listed anywhere. Are there examples of custom policies around?

Comment: [`aiogevent`](https://bitbucket.org/haypo/aiogevent/src/b419fa064416cbd9241c351be83c39269732e692/aiogevent.py?at=default#cl-290) and [`gblub`](https://github.com/m-labs/gbulb/blob/master/gbulb/glib_events.py#L643) both have custom EventLoopPolicys. It seems to be most commonly used in libraries that integrate `asyncio` with other event loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom policy is required when you implement non-default event loop.

The main problem is: I want to create new event loop by `asyncio.new_event_loop()`. It's required for threads: only main thread has implicit event loop, all other threads should instantiate loop explicitly.

But I don't know specific event loop type, thus I need a factory for loop creation -- pluggable event loop policy.

Comment: What does make "factory" a policy? This word implies some set of rules :)

Comment: IIRC Guido van Rossum called it personally. *Policy* is common pattern: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design